# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'check_password' error in django allauth

Tags: python, django, forms, passwords, django-allauth

I am using django all auth for my login and signup views and templates, but i also want to implement the change password functionality, so by default it has a template `password_change.html` that we can use, but i want a custom design, and that to dont want to get refreshed the page by using builtin `allauth` password change view, so decided to use only the `ChangePasswordForm` form of allauth by importing it in my views.

I am posting a request using ajax to a `url(view)` and returning a `Json Response`, so that i can use the response in jquery/ajax in my custom template.

**views.py**

```
from allauth.account.forms import ChangePasswordForm

@login_required
def change_password(request):
    form =  ChangePasswordForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        result = {'status':'done'}
    else:
        result = {'status':'undone', 'form_errors':form.errors}
    json_data = json.dumps(result)
    return HttpResponse(json_data, 'application/json')
```

**templates.html**

```
$('.form').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                              url: '/change_password/',
                              data: form_data,
                              success: function(response)
                                {
                                    if(response.status === 'done')
                                        console.log('great====>');
                                    ......
                                    .....   
                        }
                   });   
 });
```

and i am rendering the fields in the template individually like `form.oldpassword, form.newpassword, ....` also with the errors.

So when i submit the form without any data i am getting the correct errors messages that `this fields are required`, but when i entered just only one field `oldpassword` and submitted the form i am getting the below error

```
  File "/home/user/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 290, in _clean_fields
    value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()
  File "/home/user/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py", line 334, in clean_oldpassword
    if not self.user.check_password(self.cleaned_data.get("oldpassword")):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'check_password'
```

So after debugging i checked the value of `self.user` in clean_oldpassword validation method under ChangePasswordForm class in allauth forms.py is printing `None`, so y actually i am facing the above error ?

Why actually the user was none, when using the django allauth ChangePasswordForm ?

Am i doing anything wrong when using the `ChangePasswordForm Form` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass user object to your class:

```
form = ChangePasswordForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
```